# How to link to single facebook comment by comment_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm retrieving Facebook comments using the graph api. This also returns the id of each comment retrieved. I would like to add a direct link to each comment on Facebook, but I can't figure out what URL I should use.

I know that for example to link a profile/user by id I can use
https://facebook.com/{user_id}

What's the URL for a specific comment?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I think the structure of the URL for any post comment would be:

https://www.facebook.com/[NAME_OF_THE_PAGE]/posts/[POST_NUMBER]?comment_id=[COMMENT_ID]

The words in brackets you need to retrieve through the Graph API.
If for example you need the comment URL of a video you just replace `posts` with `video` and put the according `video_number`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @miguel, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm sure I have the right name, number and id's but I get a 'page not found'...

Comment: @Ties Do you have a valid session to retrieve the comments? If you are trying to read comments for a certain user you need granted permissions from that user to get access to it

Comment: I think so.. I did however find out that for me the following (public) urls seem to work:
https://www.facebook.com/[POST_NUMBER]?comment_id=[COMMENT_ID]